# Navigation item in Android application

Tags: android, navigationbar

Good evening.
I am new in Android Application development but I have experience of iPhone app development.
In Iphone app, we have Navigation bar and Navigation item.
in Android application, I want to use the same type of control in my application.
But don't know how to do that.
Please help me to explain navigation control in Android app.
Any step by step tutorial will be better.

Thanks in advance.

--Ruhul

Answer (score 0):

I recently had my navigation drawer set up using reference of below link. This could be the one you are looking for . Also i found it easy to understand it .. good luck :)

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

Comment: Thanks. But in Navigation drawer, the navigation items will come in the left side all together.
But in my original application( iPhone app), I have the navigation item in the top of the application. The client need the same look and feel for android also. So is there anyway( Except customize view and item) to do that and do the navigation easily?

Answer (score 0):

Use Navigation Drawer, eclipse can do it by yourself, when you create the project, use a activity with Navigation Drawer and you don't have to do nothing!

https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html

Comment: Thanks. But in Navigation drawer, the navigation items will come in the left side all together.
But in my original application( iPhone app), I have the navigation item in the top of the application. The client need the same look and feel for android also. So is there anyway( Except customize view and item) to do that and do the navigation easily?